Name mismatch in UK BRP card
I have issue regarding my name on BRP card UK and my provisional license UK.
I am just giving example to make you understand the issue:
My name on passport is Pawan Kumar.
My name on BRP Card is PRINTED :
KUMAR
PAWAN
NOTE: KUMAR IS IN THE FIRST LINE
AND PAWAN IS IN THE SECOND LINE
BOTH ARE NOT IN THE SAME LINE
AND IN MY PROVISIONAL LICENSE MY NAME IS PRINTED "MR KUMAR PAWAN" IN ONE LINE.
SO HERE I AM CONFUSED ABOUT MY NAME IS WRONG PRINTED ON BOTH BRP AND PROVIONAL LICENSE OR NOT?
IF WRONG THEN LET ME KNOW THE SOLUTION. IF NAME IS CORRECT THEN SHOULD I USE KUMAR PAWAN (BRP + PRIVISIONAL ) OR PAWAN KUMAR ( PASSPORT ) FOR MY FULL DRIVING LICENSE.
PLEASE HELP ME I NEED URGENT RESPONSE

Writing in ALL CAPITAL LETTERS is perceived as SHOUTING, is harder to read than upper- and lower-cased typography, and is unwelcome here. Please use the "Edit" button below your question and amend the text to use conventional upper- and lower-case letters. Thanks.

Is Pawan your first name and Kumar your family name? AFAIK these items are produced from information the applicant inputs. What did you input for the driving licence, for example?

Your BRP should match your visa, which should match your passport. You can report a problem with your BRP here
